# Wordpress set_permalink_structure( '/%postname%/' ) with $wp_rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

How can I change the permalink setting by functions.php (in a child theme to twentytwelve) to get it actived and working without having to do anything manually?

I guess this code should work - but it doesn't seem to .. I guess I've missed something.

```
if($run_when_theme_is_activated_and_user_wants_this_permalink_structure){
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( '/%postname%/' );
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

When I just visit the "Permalink Settings" page... wp-admin/options-permalink.php then indeed "Post name" is **already selected** and when testing now it works. So I do not have to save or anything, just visit this particular page. The step having to visit permalink settings manually should be skipped in the solution please.

Comment: I think your question is quite the same with the question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31207/how-to-set-permalink-structure-via-functions-php) See and try if it works with you.

Comment: Thanks. I tested the code, but same results.. it activates after visiting the /options-permalink.php page. I will check if this is a child theme issue to the theme twenty twelve.

Answer (score 2):

This should run when the theme is activated, so only set and flush the rules once

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'reset_permalinks' );
function reset_permalinks() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%postname%/');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution gives the same result. It activates /%postname%/ only after visting the the ..wp-admin/options-permalink.php page manually. Maybe it is a twenty twelve child theme issue.. we'll see.

Comment: //Just some code that runs once when theme is activated via wp-admin
if ( is_admin() && isset($_GET['activated'] ) && $pagenow == 'themes.php' ) {
{ //Runned once when theme is activated }

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. It will work 100%. Thanks

```
/**
 * Rewrite set up, when theme activate i mean
 */
if (isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin()) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%postname%/');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

/**
* Redirect to Permalink setting Page.
* Otherwise Redirect rule will not work Properly.
*/
function redirect_to_permalink() {

    wp_redirect('options-permalink.php');
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'redirect_to_permalink' );
```